# jquery: add choices to charfield dynamically in django admin

Tags: jquery, django, django-models, django-admin

I have declared a charfield in my model with only one choice as 'choices' and in admin page, I am adding other choices through jquery. Now when user selects one of the choices added through jquery, django admin throws error

> Select a valid choice.  is not one of the available choices.

I understand this is because these choices are not saved in the database yet. The choices that get added depend on user input to a text-box. Is there any way I add choices to the charfield dynamically before it gets saved to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it is not necessary 'save choices in database', you can define a list (with items no saved in database) and use it as list:

```
choices_list = [(1, 'one'), (2, 'two')]
...
field = models.CharField(choices=choices_list)
```

So, since it's not necessary save items in database to use them as choices and I think you don't really need a choices list, you could use a list with initial choices and show it in your template, then add or remove items and save them in database, but without using the `choices` option in your `CharField`:

```
field = models.CharField()
```

Comment: oh yes...sorry didn't think it through.